# error while importing mercurial api

Tags: python, django, mercurial

Have the next problem:

There is a django project and I need use the mercurial api in it.
When I do the next:

```
from mercurial import hg,ui
```

I get error:

```
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value: cannot import name hg
Exception Location: //some.py in , line 1
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.6
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    ['/usr/lib/python2.6', .... '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0']
```

there is **'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6'** in the PythonPath where mercurial package is placed.
evev when I added **/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/mercurial** into the PythonPath does not solve the problem.

Do you have any suggestion? 
Thanks

Comment: hm, no repro. is your mercurial package up to date? can you just do `import mercurial`?

Comment: Note that "Cannot import *name* ..." is not the same as "No module named...". I think this implies that the problem is not with your Python path, at least.

Comment: I have mercurial v1.6.3. I wrote a test program where I use mercurial api and do the same import <code>from mercurial import hg,ui</code> and it works.

Comment: @Cameron if I import "from mercurial.hg import repository" it says "No module named hg"

Comment: So the error is only occurring when you run the Django app? Have you tried `from mercurial import hg, ui` while in the Django shell?

Comment: @Jordan Reiter: good idea. there is "Exception Value: cannot import name hg" in the django shell but no errors in the python interpreter shell. hm, django uses own import or modifies smth.?

Comment: solved! thanks to all. The problem was I had a django project with name mercurial and django imprted my mercurial. after i`ve removed mercurial proj all is ok.